# Chrome Toggle different devices view destroys the session

Tags: php, google-chrome

I am working on a website admin cp with PHP as a back end technology  and in the same time I am fixing some responsive issues.

So I am logged in to the admin panel But when i toggle different devices such as Galaxy, Nexus Iphone or even responsive mode to test the responsive look or fixes that i have done i find myself logged out and redirected to login page and also i see things that shouldn't appear before login  such as admin menu but it is not accessible in other words it's half logged in and half not.

cashing is not disabled.

session id is the same i can see it.

I really can't get my head around it!

Is that something normal in the browser which means every device is independent from the whole browser?

Or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Check that when you open the console, disable cache is unchecked

Comment: @JoaquinPeraza no cahsing is not disabled !

Comment: How do you check for login status?

Comment: @Akintunde by sessions

Comment: We need more info about your login script. There are many possibilities. Maybe you have a cookie too or your login script dont allow another browser/device with this session id, but is not destroying your session correctly...

Comment: @A.Blub no im using only session not cookies at all here is the login method check it out https://codeshare.io/GqNM3M

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally and after several hours of reviewing my code and debugging every single thing I came up with a solution to my problem :

- my hypothesis in the question that the devices are independent
  from each other is quite correct because every device has a different
  `HTTP_USER_AGENT`

You can try it like this :

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Toggle different devices on the browser and see the result .

So as for sessions best practice  based on stack overflow and many other resources it is a good practice to save `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in a session and later on check the session after login which means the logged in user is exactly the user coming from that browser

And that's what i was doing i was checking for the user login session and the user agent session

And that's what was causing the problem so when i toggle different devices the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` gets changed so the session doesn't match and therefore i get logged out automatically.

Comment: I just seen this question and was going to say it's quite clear your doing user agent validation `$this->session->set('agent', $this->custom->userAgent());` and chromes device view changes it to the user agent of the device you have set it to...

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-simulate-mobile-devices-with-device-mode-in-chrome/